# How to make a table with no same values in non of the columns in My SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I try to join two tables in my SQL for the results I need the columns to be in a distinct format
but using DISTINCT does not help

I have table 1 as

```
id_1  favourite_color
1      pink
2      yellow
3      green
4      yellow
```

table 2 is

```
color    cloth_id
pink     101
green    102
blue     103
yellow   104
yellow   105
```

I want this

```
id_1   cloth_id
1        101
2        104
3        102
```

with no duplicated value in the columns as if I can only distribute one clothes from each color.

Thanks guys

Comment: I'd start with GROUP BY in subqueries, then JOIN the results.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id_1, cloth_id
FROM table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN table_2 t2 ON t2.color = t1.favourite_color
GROUP BY t1.favourite_color
ORDER BY t1.id_1
```